# how to get the lines from one pattern to other pattern when those pattern are repeated by sed command

Tags: shell, unix, powershell, command-line, command

if i have file like this

test.txt

```
abc naveen
abc cde
naveen cde
kumar
naveen
abc 
cde
abc
naveen
cde
```

Question 1: In this we have repeated patterns like abc, navee, cdf etc
Now we have to get the lines from first occurrence of one pattern to any second occurrence of another pattern
  For example, I want to get the lines from the 2nd occurrence of abc to the 3rd occurrence of `naveen` i.e we get output as

```
abc cde
naveen cde
kumar
naveen
```

Question 2 (this question is continue to above question):
I want to get only the lines between them (exclude those `abc` and `naveen` )

So, I want output as

```
cde
naveen cde
kumar
```

this can be done by using `sed` command ....
so any one please give me the answer for this

Comment: Why have you tagged this as both `unix`/`shell` AND `powershell`? Do you want to use `sed` or `powershell`?

Comment: you need on the basis of first field only (1st column in each line) or you can change to other columns??

Comment: I don't know why people downgraded it , its really a challenging question

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    a=2
    b=3
    abcocc=`awk '$0~/abc/{print NR}' txt | awk -v occ=$a 'NR==occ{print $0}' `
    naveenocc=`awk '$0~/naveen/{print NR}' txt | awk -v occ=$b 'NR==occ{print $0}'`
1)  awk -v abc=$abcocc -v naveen=$naveenocc 'NR>=abc&&NR<=naveen{print $0}' txt
2)  awk -v abc=$abcocc -v naveen=$naveenocc 'NR>abc&&NR<naveen{print $0}' txt
```

a is occurrence of abc and b is occurrence of Naveen and txt is input file. try and let me know if modification is needed.

Comment: we want solution in sed command.   input is a file not a record with column names!!!

Comment: In my answer your test.txt is my txt file. I am doing operation on txt file replace it with your filename and why it has to be in sed only?can you explain that